# Matplotlib - place pie charts in a grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, pie-chart

I am trying to organize pie charts in a grid, with another column on the left in which I write some relevant data on the pie charts of the specific row. Right now my code is:

```
data = [[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1],[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4]]


def main():
    createPieCharts(data)
    return 0


def createPieCharts(data,piecharts_fname="piecharts"):
    """ """
    import datetime
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    areas = ['Arava','Lotz','Paran','Ramon']
    thresholds = [0.0,0.01,0.02]
    num_columns = len(areas)
    num_rows    = len(thresholds)
    with PdfPages(piecharts_fname+'.pdf') as pdf:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_rows,num_columns)
#            fig.suptitle('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
        labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
        for i,threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
            fracs = data[i]
            for j,area in enumerate(areas):
                ax[i,j].set_title(area)
                ax[i,j].pie(fracs, labels=labels,
                            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                ax[i,j].set_aspect('equal')
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close()
        # Adding metadata for PDF file
        d = pdf.infodict()
        d['Title'] = 'Pie charts'
        d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the result looks like this
[image]
While I would like it to have another column on the left like in this example - 
[image]

What is the smart way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Add an extra column, and put your text in there.

You then just need to turn off the axes lines and ticks from the axes in the left column ([`ax.set_axis_off()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_off)), and the add your text labels using `ax.text`.

Note you also need to add 1 to the j index for the other axes where you plot your pie charts.

Here's the function from your script, modified:

```
def createPieCharts(data,piecharts_fname="piecharts"):
    """ """
    import datetime
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    areas = ['Arava','Lotz','Paran','Ramon']
    thresholds = [0.0,0.01,0.02]
    num_columns = len(areas) + 1                                # Add extra column for text
    num_rows    = len(thresholds)
    with PdfPages(piecharts_fname+'.pdf') as pdf:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_rows,num_columns)
#            fig.suptitle('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})
        labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
        for i,threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
            fracs = data[i]
            ax[i,0].set_axis_off()                                  # Turn off axes & ticks
            ax[i,0].text(0.5,0.5,threshold,ha='center',va='center') # Add text
            for j,area in enumerate(areas):
                ax[i,j+1].set_title(area)                           # Add 1 to j index
                ax[i,j+1].pie(fracs, labels=labels,                 # Add 1 to j index
                            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                ax[i,j+1].set_aspect('equal')                       # Add 1 to j index
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close()
        # Adding metadata for PDF file
        d = pdf.infodict()
        d['Title'] = 'Pie charts'
        d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use special functions for an axis object `is_first_col` to label y axis and `is_last_row` for x axis:

```
def createPieCharts(data,piecharts_fname="piecharts"):
    """ """
    import datetime
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    areas = ['Arava','Lotz','Paran','Ramon']
    thresholds = [0.0,0.01,0.02]
    num_columns = len(areas)
    num_rows    = len(thresholds)
    val = 0. # to y axis labels
    with PdfPages(piecharts_fname+'.pdf') as pdf:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_rows,num_columns)
        labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
        for i,threshold in enumerate(thresholds):
            fracs = data[i]
            for j,area in enumerate(areas):
                ax[i,j].set_title(area)
                ax[i,j].pie(fracs, labels=labels,
                            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                ax[i,j].set_aspect('equal')
                # label y axis
                if ax[i,j].is_first_col():
                    ax[i,j].set_ylabel(str(val), fontsize = 9, rotation = 0)
                    val += .01
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close()
        # Adding metadata for PDF file
        d = pdf.infodict()
        d['Title'] = 'Pie charts'
        d['CreationDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
```

[image]